# ASP.NET MVC - Select from two tables then compare

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have this `Wishlist` class:

```cs
public class Wishlist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public string PersonId { get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Person { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool Featured { get; set; }
    public bool Sold { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage { get; set; }
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Person { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get all the products added to `dbcontext.Wishlist` table, by using:

```cs
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var list2 = DbContext.Wishlist.Where(p => p.PersonId == currentUserId).ToList();
var list3 = (from p in DbContext.Products
             from w in list2
             where p.PersonId == w.PersonId
             select new Models.Response.ProductIndexResponse()
             {
               Id = p.Id,
               Image = p.Image,
               Title = p.Title,
               Price = p.Price
             }).ToList();
```

But I get this error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Finder.Models.Wishlist'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: on which line that error being thrown? is it on `list3`? i had doubts on `select new Models.Response.ProductIndexResponse()` whether it works in sql query.

Comment: @BagusTesa I don't know if external links are allowed, but :https://imgur.com/a/J5PywuU

Comment: you can edit your question and put that image on the question - given you have provided the code in text, error message should be fine. also, see Yong's answer. i missed that you passed `list2` on `list3`, which also an illegal move XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to simplify you query like this:

```
var wishPorducts = DbContext.Wishlist
    .Where(p => p.PersonId == currentUserId)
    .Select(x => new Models.Response.ProductIndexResponse()
         {
           Id = x.Product.Id,
           Image = x.Product.Image,
           Title = x.Product.Title,
           Price = x.Product.Price
         })
     .ToList();
```

The query above is much simpler and efficient and may help you better understand where is the issue if it still there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can pass the list of `WishList` to LINQ.

Instead, modify your LINQ query with `JOIN` as below:

```cs
var query = (from p in DbContext.Products
             join w in DbContext.Wishlist on p.PersonId equals w.PersonId
             where p.PersonId == currentUserId
             select new
             {
               Id = p.Id,
               Image = p.Image,
               Title = p.Title,
               Price = p.Price
             }).ToList();

var result = query
    .Select(x => Models.Response.ProductIndexResponse()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Image = x.Image,
        Title = x.Title,
        Price = x.Price
    })
    .ToList();
```